# edit the dropped elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have dropped the elements in the page. now i have to edit it. like i drag element from widget and drop in the page. after drop when i select the element it selected. can i edit its name like div.`<div class="inputBoxItem-label">Text </div>.`

i want to change the div name text to text1 after dropped. how can be it possiible in jquery.

here is my code..

```
 jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({
    activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
    accept:  '.item-art',
    revert: true,
    drop:  function (event, ui) {
      var $canvas = jQuery(this);
      if(!ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {
        var $canvasElement = ui.draggable.clone().text('dropped');
        $canvasElement.addClass('canvas-element');
        $canvas.append($canvasElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$canvasElement.html('Text1')` before calling `$canvas.append($canvasElement);`